# Ruby on Rails Active Record RANDOM() always the same within a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, activerecord

Why does this output the same record ID repeatedly, when it should be grabbing a random record each loop iteration?

```
count = 0
while count < 20
  puts "ID: " + SomeModel.where(assoc_id: 10).order("RANDOM()").limit(1).first.id.to_s
  count += 1
end
```

Output:

```
ID: 82784
ID: 82784
ID: 82784
ID: 82784
ID: 82784
```

I have already ensured there are sufficient records available with the query (ie more than 1).  Within a console, the line by itself (outside of a loop) will return a new ID every time, so it has something to do with the loop.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: Do you test in in browser or with test instruments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that's happening because of **ActiveRecord caching**. You can read [this blog post](http://adamnengland.com/2014/08/14/avoiding-caching-with-rails-activerecord/) about something very similar to your problem and their solution. In short, they (and you) can make use of [ActiveRecords uncached method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-uncached) to not see it repeating.