# Unique Random Record in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Question table in which there is id# and title as columns.
Now, I need to randomly select 5 questions from the table. I am seeing people are using:

```
Question.order("RANDOM()").limit(5) //using postgre
```

Till now I have:

```
def selectr
        @randquestion=[]
        while @randquestion.length<3 do
            Question.uncached do
                ques=Question.order("RANDOM()").first
                @randquestion << ques
            end
        end
end
```

I found uncaching from [Ruby on Rails Active Record RANDOM() always the same within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583074/ruby-on-rails-active-record-random-always-the-same-within-a-loop).

But I am not sure if this will give me unique questions. I want 3 unique questions only.

Comment: Did you try the code?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I forgot to add my code...Sorry

Comment: I don't understand why would you do that. If you see `Question.order("RANDOM()")` it gives you all your records, but in a random order, so in your case you pick up one, with first. If you can pass a limit you would skip all the while and pushing steps, and even, you can. Aren't you using Postgres?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I have tried Question.order("RANDOM()").limit(3) also actually but it is giving me the same id always. So, I am not sure.

Comment: Try `1000.times.map { Question.order("RANDOM()").limit(1).pluck(:id) }.uniq`, if you see multiple arrays within an array, then it works. If not, then check you have several records for question in your db.

Comment: @SebastianPalma: 
When I try:
`3.times.map { Question.order("RANDOM()").limit(1).pluck(:qid) }.uniq`

I get 
`CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions"."qid" FROM "questions" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]` but then I used :
`Question.uncached do ` and it works...Thank you.

Comment: Didn't understand what you do, for sure you can create your own answer.

Comment: Are you sure `RANDOM()` is a function that your SQL database understands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by fetching each question via a separate SQL request, with subsequent requests excluding IDs for records already seen. Here's an example, tested with Rails 5.2 and MySQL:

```
def random_questions(number)
  already_seen = []
  number.times.map do
    question = Question.order('RAND()').where.not(id: already_seen).first
    already_seen << question.id
    question
  end
end
```

If you try this out with `random_questions(3)`, you'll see:

```
Question Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
Question Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`id` != 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
Question Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`id` NOT IN (2, 1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

As an aside, please note that `order('RAND()')` triggers a deprecation warning in newer versions of Rails:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "RAND()". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().

To avoid this warning, use `.order(Arel.sql('RAND()'))` instead.

Comment: number.times.map doesn't guarantee that the length of already_seen will have the desired length actually. I think I need to use while loop and compare while already_seen.length. Let me know if it is incorrect. Thank you very much